# Calculator Script or Plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for the Calculator Plugin (for Wordpress) or Script which should work in such a way:

Should be only one field where user can type the number of my product (Instagram Likes). And depending on the number the cost changes.

I'v got the variety of prices for different Likes number. For example:

- 1-10000 likes = 0,0009 per 1 like
- 10001-50000 = 0,0008 per 1 like etc

And if the user type the number 5555 it should automatically count 5555*0.0009

Could you, please, help me?

Comment: please put here the code you try, so we can help you, and if you dont try it first, please try it first,

Comment: @mmativ thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, my JS knowledge is extremely bad. That's why I ask for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one.

```js
function priceCalculation(a){
   if(a <= 10000){
     return 0.0009;
   }else if(a >= 10001 && a <= 25000 ){
     return 0.0008;
   }else if(a >= 25001 && a <= 50000 ){
     return 0.0007;
   }else if(a >= 50001 && a <= 100000 ){
     return 0.0005;
   }else{
     return 0.0004;
   }
}


$('#likecount').keyup(function(){
  var price = priceCalculation($(this).val());
  console.log(price)
  var total = $(this).val() * price;
  $('#output').text(total.toFixed(4));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="likecount" />
<p>Price: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

Comment: please try to ask, if i can help,

Comment: 1. How can I make the field count automatically, without the check button?
2. I have 4 pricing variations. (0-10000 (0.0009$ per 1)),(10001-25000 (0.0008$ per 1)),(25001-50000 (0.0007$ per 1)),(50001-100000 (0.0005$ per 1)),(and >100001 (0.0004$ per 1)). Where should I put these numbers in this code? Thank you in advance, your help is invaluable!

Comment: It looks like it's working to me :) Thank you so much @mmativ

Answer (score 4):

```
var likes = document.getElementById("your id for likes").value;
var costPerLike;
if(likes <= 10000){costPerLike = 0.0009} else if(likes >= 10001 && likes <= 50000){costPerLike = 0.0008}
```

i think this should help you get in the right direction.

you probably want this in an onchange or onsubmit event.